# ASP MVC 4 - cannot find view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

Error:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/Index.aspx
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/Index.ascx
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Calendar/Index.aspx ~/Views/Calendar/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/Index.vbhtml
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Calendar/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Calendar/Index.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

My folder structure is as follows:

```
MVCApp.WebUI
- Areas
  -AdminAssignment
    -Controllers
    -Models
    -Views
      -Calendar
        -Index.cshtml
```

when i try to browse directly to Index.cshtml I receive a HTTP 404 error. I tried changing the build on the view to 'content' but that didn't do anything. Completely confused as to why it cannot find it considering '~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/Index.cshtml' is the actual path of the file.

Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the action impelmentation that return the view, please

Comment: Are you able to find any other views in that folder/area?

Comment: No action. It's just URL link on another view: basically a link to:localhost:56079/AdminAssignment/Calendar

Comment: And no, can't find other views in that folder/area :(

Comment: Go to the relevant view properties and make sure `BuildAction=Content` and `Copy to Output Directory=Do not copy`

Comment: @OrelEraki it's already set to that

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at URL in error message.
The following locations were searched: 
this is not correct
~/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/***Index.aspx*** 
correct url:
/Areas/AdminAssignment/Views/Calendar/***Index***

Comment: How do i fix this or change it?

Comment: How did you call view

Comment: localhost:56079/AdminAssignment/Calendar

Comment: in action call url or other view?

Comment: View is not connected to action. 
Do the following tasks.
1- delete Index view
2- go to Calendar controller
3- go to index action
4- right click and add view
5- build and run

Comment: I have tested. when disconnect view to action display some error. connect action to view solve this error.